# Flex use MySql date to update datepicker

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex3

I receive a mysql date from a webservice like `2014-05-22`.

I want to be able to use this as the selected date in a datepicker.

I tried `date.selectedDate = itemSelected.date;` but it remains empty.

How can i reformat the date to work?

Comment: Do you mean DateChooser?

Comment: @GaryPerry - its like this '<mx:DateField id="date" yearNavigationEnabled="true" selectableRange="{{rangeStart: new Date()}} " />'

Comment: Which version of the Flex SDK are you using?  This shouldn't be tagged with both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty simple.
Read something about [String](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html) class

```
var arr1:Array = "2014-05-22".split("-");
var date:Date = new Date(arr1[0], arr1[1] - 1, arr1[2]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem on my Java Server, retrieving the date from MySQL using date did not format the date properly, try this(if using Java):

```
Timestamp time = resultSet.getTimestamp(2);
Date date = new Date(time.getTime());
```

I have used this date in Flex and it gives no problem

Answer (score 1):

You can use the static method in the mx.formatters.DateFormatter class.

DateFormatter.parseDateString(dateString);

In this case

```
var dateFromSql:Date =  DateFormatter.parseDateString(itemSelected.date.toString());
date.selectedDate = dateFromSql;
```